# tf.image.crop_and_resize for 3D image

Tags: python, tensorflow

`tf.image.crop_and_resize` deals with 2D image, which is a 4-D tensor of shape `[batch, image_height, image_width, depth]`.

However, I wanna process 3D image, which is a 5-D tensor of shape `[batch, image_height, image_width, image_depth, 1]`. My boxes is `[y1, x1, z1, y2, x2, z2]`. My crop_size is `[crop_height, crop_width, crop_depth]`.

How can I crop and resize a 3D image? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer or workaround on this?